# How to change the height of a Textarea on a mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, textarea

I am trying to do something like this.

- I want to increase the height of textarea when the user clicks a button

For this I have made a button like this `<a id="expandText" href="#"> Expand </a>` and added the following javascript

```
$('#expandText').click(function () {
    $('#id_text').animate({ height: "1000px" }, 500);
    //$('#id_text').css( "height","+=85" );
});
```

I tried two things

1. One was to animate the height of the text box
2. The other was to change the css, but neither of them has worked

**Edit:**
I tried out all the things that have been given below, but it is still not working. Could it be possible because this textarea has a class = MCeEditor which makes this textarea an editor and not just a normal text area

Comment: 'animate' is working on my end... which browser you are using? and also include the 'textarea' html

Comment: A fiddle demonstrating that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/dEDfv/

Comment: "The other was to change the css" - Can you provide us with the pertinent CSS?

Comment: The css file just contains this textarea#id_text
{
 border:none;
 height:400px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the textarea has the class `MCeEditor` - so I'm guessing that's TinyMCE or something of that kind.

If so, use inspect element in whatever browser you're using (hold down CTRL to get browser context menu if TinyMCE context menu shows up), and navigate your way down through the editor till you find an iframe which is where the writing really happens. If I'm not mistaken, the selector `.mceEditor iframe` should do.

The reason for all thiss hazzle, is that TinyMCE hides your actual textarea, and creates an editor on its own. As you type into TinyMCE, it puts that text back into your textarea so you can retrieve it as expected from server side. So when you see the MCE editor, you aren't directly manipulating your textarea as one might expect.

Comment: Yes I am using TinyMCE and thanks a lot for the information on how it works.. But I have not really understood what you mean by inspect element. Could you please explain how I should actually do it

Comment: @Sachin The right click-menu in proper browsers (Opera, Firefox, Safari or Chrome) has an element in it called "Inspect element". Right click somewhere and hit that, and you'll see the actual generated DOM (after JS-modifications etc) that the browser is currently rendering. Inspect within and just besides the TinyMCE-editor and you'll see what I mean :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's weird, as your code should work. Do you have any error? Does it work when you run directly `$('#id_text').animate({ height: "1000px" }, 500);` on a JS console? One more thing is you may want to add "return false" like this

```
$('#expandText').click(function () {
    $('#id_text').animate({ height: "1000px" }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

to avoid the link action when you click on the link.

**EDIT:** you've added "*this textarea has a class = MCeEditor*", so I think you misunderstand something. What you see is an editable content (span or div), not a textarea (which is actually hidden). You need to resize this element (and probably you should use TinyMCE API to do that).

Answer (score 0):

I've read the doc and you may just use:

```
$('#id_text').animate({ height: 1000 }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine. See here in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/URkWu/

Let me know if you don't see the textbox animating.

Comment: Yes I checked it at JSFiddle there it seems to be working fine. It is not the problem of js because another js code snipet is working fine